# Listpicker in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to use the listpicker control in windows phone 7.
Such that i am trying to get the value of the selected item from the **listpicker**.

Below is my code for the listpicker.

```
 this.queListPicker.ItemsSource = new List<string>() {"5", "10", "15" };
```

I want it to be something like when i click on the listpicker and 
clicked on "10" i will have a textblock showing the value of 10.
While when i click on 15 it will show the value of 15 in the text block

How should i go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the *SelectionChanged* event of the *listpicker*. You can then get the corresponding argument (such as the item being selected) using the *SelectionChangedEventArgs* of the event. Many list controls such as *ListBox* has similar approach (same event), so you might want to get started from [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use a binding to picker.SelectedItem